# Specify performance category name from property in WIx

Tags: wix, performancecounter, wix3.5

I'm trying to create a performance category as part of the WIX installation but trying to pass in a property to the category's name just results in the performance category taking the name literally.

```
<util:PerformanceCategory Id="PerformanceCounter" Name="[PERFORMANCE_CATEGORY_NAME]" DefaultLanguage="english">
```

Is it possible for it to get the name from a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sources of the WiX toolset, the Name column value of PerformanceCategory MSI table is read using WcaGetRecordString function, which doesn't consider formatted values and passes the value as it is written in @Name attribute. I don't know whether it was an intention or just a simple oversight, but if it uses WcaGetRecordFormattedString for the same purpose one day, it will work the way you expect it to now.

Comment: Remember that it's all in your power, actually. It's open source, and even if your patch is not accepted, you can create a custom build just for yourself ;-)

Comment: I'm still on the learning curve with Wix so its a bit daunting right now but hopefully I'll get there.

Comment: Please file a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642717) so it doesn't get lost. (And I agree with Yan, it's an easy change.)

Comment: Here you go: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3388657&group_id=105970&atid=642717

Answer (score -1):

PERFORMANCE_CATEGORY_NAME variable must be defined in Product.wxs(main wix file) file. Once it is defined then you can have the value of the variable